# Capture video : SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, video, swiftui, avcapturesession

I want to capture a video through back camera using swiftUI. I can not find the proper solution on on video recording. I implement the code that record video automatically when view is open But I want to start the recording on bottom button click. Can someone please guide me on this.

```
 import SwiftUI
    import AVKit
    
    struct RecordingView: View {
        @State private var timer = 5
        @State private var onComplete = false
        @State private var recording = false
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VideoRecordingView(timeLeft: $timer, onComplete: $onComplete, recording: $recording)
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {self.recording.toggle()}, label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                        
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(Color.white,lineWidth: 2)
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                    }
                })
                    Button(action: {
                        self.timer -= 1
                        print(self.timer)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Toggle timer")
                    })
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                    Button(action: {
                        self.onComplete.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Toggle completion")
                    })
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

> This is For recordingView

```
struct VideoRecordingView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var timeLeft: Int
    @Binding var onComplete: Bool
    @Binding var recording: Bool
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<VideoRecordingView>) -> PreviewView {
        let recordingView = PreviewView()
        recordingView.onComplete = {
            self.onComplete = true
        }
        
        recordingView.onRecord = { timeLeft, totalShakes in
            self.timeLeft = timeLeft
            self.recording = true
        }
        
        recordingView.onReset = {
            self.recording = false
            self.timeLeft = 30
        }
        return recordingView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiViewController: PreviewView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<VideoRecordingView>) {
        
    }
}

extension PreviewView: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate{
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        print(outputFileURL.absoluteString)
    }
}

class PreviewView: UIView {
    private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    private var shakeCountDown: Timer?
    let videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate!
    var recorded = 0
    var secondsToReachGoal = 30
    
    var onRecord: ((Int, Int)->())?
    var onReset: (() -> ())?
    var onComplete: (() -> ())?
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        var allowedAccess = false
        let blocker = DispatchGroup()
        blocker.enter()
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { flag in
            allowedAccess = flag
            blocker.leave()
        }
        blocker.wait()
        
        if !allowedAccess {
            print("!!! NO ACCESS TO CAMERA")
            return
        }
        
        // setup session
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.beginConfiguration()
        
        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                                  for: .video, position: .front)
        guard videoDevice != nil, let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!), session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
            print("!!! NO CAMERA DETECTED")
            return
        }
        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
        session.commitConfiguration()
        self.captureSession = session
    }
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        recordingDelegate = self
        startTimers()
        if nil != self.superview {
            self.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.captureSession
            self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
            self.captureSession?.startRunning()
            self.startRecording()
        } else {
            self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
        }
    }
    
    private func onTimerFires(){
        print(" RECORDING \(videoFileOutput.isRecording)")
        secondsToReachGoal -= 1
        recorded += 1
        onRecord?(secondsToReachGoal, recorded)
        
        if(secondsToReachGoal == 0){
            stopRecording()
            shakeCountDown?.invalidate()
            shakeCountDown = nil
            onComplete?()
            videoFileOutput.stopRecording()
        }
    }
    
    func startTimers(){
        if shakeCountDown == nil {
            shakeCountDown = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] (timer) in
                self?.onTimerFires()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func startRecording(){
        captureSession?.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
        
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("tempPZDC")
        
        videoFileOutput.startRecording(to: filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
    }
    
    func stopRecording(){
        videoFileOutput.stopRecording()
        print(" RECORDING \(videoFileOutput.isRecording)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code by this

```
struct VideoRecordingView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var timeLeft: Int
    @Binding var onComplete: Bool
    @Binding var recording: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<VideoRecordingView>) -> PreviewView {
        let recordingView = PreviewView()
        recordingView.onComplete = {
            self.onComplete = true
        }
        
        recordingView.onRecord = { timeLeft, totalShakes in
            self.timeLeft = timeLeft
            self.recording = true
        }
        
        recordingView.onReset = {
            self.recording = false
            self.timeLeft = 30
        }
        return recordingView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiViewController: PreviewView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<VideoRecordingView>) {
        if recording {
            uiViewController.start()
        }
    }
}

extension PreviewView: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate{
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        print(outputFileURL.absoluteString)
    }
}

class PreviewView: UIView {
    private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    private var shakeCountDown: Timer?
    let videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate!
    var recorded = 0
    var secondsToReachGoal = 30
    
    var onRecord: ((Int, Int)->())?
    var onReset: (() -> ())?
    var onComplete: (() -> ())?
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        var allowedAccess = false
        let blocker = DispatchGroup()
        blocker.enter()
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { flag in
            allowedAccess = flag
            blocker.leave()
        }
        blocker.wait()
        
        if !allowedAccess {
            print("!!! NO ACCESS TO CAMERA")
            return
        }
        
        // setup session
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.beginConfiguration()
        
        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                                  for: .video, position: .front)
        guard videoDevice != nil, let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!), session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
            print("!!! NO CAMERA DETECTED")
            return
        }
        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
        session.commitConfiguration()
        self.captureSession = session
    }
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        recordingDelegate = self
    }
    
    func start() {
        startTimers()
        if nil != self.superview {
            self.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.captureSession
            self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
            self.captureSession?.startRunning()
            self.startRecording()
        } else {
            self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
        }
    }
    private func onTimerFires(){
        print(" RECORDING \(videoFileOutput.isRecording)")
        secondsToReachGoal -= 1
        recorded += 1
        onRecord?(secondsToReachGoal, recorded)
        
        if(secondsToReachGoal == 0){
            stopRecording()
            shakeCountDown?.invalidate()
            shakeCountDown = nil
            onComplete?()
            videoFileOutput.stopRecording()
        }
    }
    
    func startTimers(){
        if shakeCountDown == nil {
            shakeCountDown = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] (timer) in
                self?.onTimerFires()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func startRecording(){
        captureSession?.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
        
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("tempPZDC")
        
        videoFileOutput.startRecording(to: filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
    }
    
    func stopRecording(){
        videoFileOutput.stopRecording()
        print(" RECORDING \(videoFileOutput.isRecording)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what did you change? Also is it possible to display preview until press record button?

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia I just moved to start recording code from didMoveToSuperview function and call the function inside the updateUIView. and for the second question "display preview until press" yes it possible but need to modify more code.